# sstream string wrong output

Tags: c++, sstream

I am trying to read a string of three number using sstream but when I try to print them, I am getting a wrong output with four numbers.

Code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>

using namespace std;

int main() {
    string a("1 2 3");

    istringstream my_stream(a);

    int n;

    while(my_stream) {
        my_stream >> n;
        cout << n << "\n";
    }
}
```

Output:

```
1
2
3
3
```

Why I get four numbers in the output compared to three numbers in input string?

Comment: `while(my_stream) ` -> `while(my_stream >> n) { cout ... }`

Comment: That was by mistake. Deleted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are printing the data before checking if readings are successful.

```
    while(my_stream) {
        my_stream >> n;
```

should be

```
    while(my_stream >> n) {
```

Related (doesn't seem duplicate because `eof()` isn't used here):
[c++ - Why is iostream::eof inside a loop condition (i.e. `while (!stream.eof())`) considered wrong? - Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5605125/why-is-iostreameof-inside-a-loop-condition-i-e-while-stream-eof-cons)

Answer (score 2):

Here

```
while ( my_stream )
```

`my_stream` is convertible to `bool` and returns `true` if there's no I/O error.

See: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_ios/operator_bool

So, after the last reading, there's no I/O error yet, so it iterates again and there's an error and nothing is read into `n` in this statement:

```
my_stream >> n;
```

And, `std::cout` prints the last extracted value again i.e. 3.

The solution could be to directly check I/O error after reading in `while` (preferred):

```
while ( my_stream >> n )
{
    std::cout << n << '\n';
}
```

or, print only if the reading is successful using an `if`:

```
while ( my_stream )
{
    if ( my_stream >> n ) // print if there's no I/O error
    {
        std::cout << n << '\n';
    }
}
```

Example ([live](https://godbolt.org/z/j-ysYK)):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>

int main()
{
    std::string a { "1 2 3" };

    std::istringstream iss{ a };

    int n {0};

    while ( iss >> n )
    {
        std::cout << n << '\n';
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
1
2
3
```

Relevant: [Why is "using namespace std;" considered bad practice?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1452721/why-is-using-namespace-std-considered-bad-practice)